# Преобразовать массив строк в массив чисел

Tags: массивы, php

Добрый день, я с php не очень и т.к. уже с трудом соображаю, как вот это

```
[["06:07:38","12121"],["06:07:38","12121"],["06:07:39","12121"],["06:07:39","12121"],["06:07:40","12121"],["06:07:40","12121"],["06:07:41","12121"],["06:07:41","12121"]]
```

это как бы массив строк преобразовать в массив чисел, типа

```
[[06:07:38,12121],[06:07:38,1212 ],и т.д.
```

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Это время? "06:07:38"

Comment: да, оно самое.

Comment: Извините, а зачем в php строки преобразовывать в числа? Это не одно и то же?

Comment: @Rumato, `"06:07:40"` в `06:07:40` вы не переведёте никогда. А "12121" это и так число. Так что задача непонятна.

Comment: Всё, разобрался, вернее начал по другому пути идти, просто в примере как работать с одной библиотекой в примере было что-то типа  [[06:07:38,12121], вот и я решил, делать так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задумка такая: надо просто время перевести в секунты и вуаля!

```
<?php

$myarray = array(array("06:07:38","12121"), array("06:07:39","12121"));

for ($i=0; $i <count($myarray) ; $i++){ 
    $myarray[$i][0] = time2seconds($myarray[$i][0]);

}
var_dump($myarray);

function time2seconds($time='00:00:00')
{
    list($hours, $mins, $secs) = explode(':', $time);
    return ($hours * 3600 ) + ($mins * 60 ) + $secs;
}

?>
```

Comment: Как вариант. Спасибо, я немного разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

Ну и функциональный вариант от меня.
Чисто ради фана.
Если будет желание разобраться.

В одну строчку:

```
$arr=[
["06:07:38","12121"],
["06:07:38","12121"],
["06:07:39","12121"],
["06:07:39","12121"],
["06:07:40","12121"],
["06:07:40","12121"],
["06:07:41","12121"],
["06:07:41","12121"]];

var_dump(
    array_map(function($x){return([array_reduce(array_map(function($t,$i){return($i*$t);},explode(':',$x[0]),[3600,60,1]),function($sum,$seconds){return($sum+$seconds);},0),(int)$x[1]]);},$arr)
);
```

С разбором и комментариями:
Суть подхода в том, чтобы для каждого элемента массива, будь то внешний или внутренний уровень, мы делаем как бы карту отображения из того, что есть, в то, чем должно стать.
Т. е. в ответ на каждый текущий элемент, мы возвращаем (`return`) **соответствующий** такой-то и строим, таким образом, карту соответствия:

```
$arr=[
["06:07:38","12121"],
["06:07:38","12121"],
["06:07:39","12121"],
["06:07:39","12121"],
["06:07:40","12121"],
["06:07:40","12121"],
["06:07:41","12121"],
["06:07:41","12121"]];

var_dump(
array_map(
    function($x){ //$x - элементы верхнего уровня (массив из времени и числа)
        return([
            array_reduce(  //первый внутренний элемент - схлопываем секунды
                array_map(
                    function($t,$i){return($i*$t);}, //возвращаем перемноженные значения. $t - число времени, $i - перемножающий коэффициент
                    explode(':',$x[0]), //разделяем строку времени 
                    [3600,60,1]         //массив коэффициентов перемножения 
                ),
                function($sum,$seconds){return($sum+$seconds);}, //функция схлопывания
                0 //стартовое значение для суммирования
            ),
            (int)$x[1]     //второй внутренний элемент - 12121
        ]);
    },
    $arr
)
);
```

Comment: В php есть `array_sum`

Comment: А ёщё можно было на `$t*pow(60, $i)` маппить

Comment: Да, я изначально так и сделал, но потом решил, что и так слишком накручено выходит, и отказался от этого варианта